# title_permalink is showing entry number instead of url_title

Tags: playa, url, url-title

Never seen this before so I'm guessing it will probably be something small I missed. I have a title_permalink that is generating a url with the entry_id at the end instead of the url_title. The enewsletter_articles tag is a Playa field...

The generated url is **site.com/enewsletter/article/255**
it should be **site.com/enewseltter/article/article-url-title**

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='enewsletter_issue' disable='categories|member_data|pagination' limit="1" dynamic="no" sort="asc"} 
    <h4>{title}</h4>
    {enewsletter_articles}
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        {summary}
        <a href="{permalink=enewsletter/article}">&raquo; Read More</a>
    {/enewsletter_articles}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: In the code, you are using {permalink=enewsletter/article} instead of {title_permalink=enewsletter/article}. "permalink" always generates an URL with entry_id where "title_permalink" generates with url_title.

Comment: Wow, how many times have I done this? haha. I even typed it correctly in my problem description in this post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using {permalink=enewsletter/article} in your code.

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#permalink

That will return an id

What you want is {title_permalink="enewsletter/article"}